# Kafka security: allowing only certain users to read certain messages, within a single topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a requirement where we will be "firehosing" a bunch of different providers' financial price feeds into a single "market data" topic in Kafka. Thing is, some of those providers have finely grained permissioning requirements, right down to individual securities. Without creating different topics for each different permissioning grain, is there a way to prevent Kafka clients from receiving information based on what's inside a message? IE can Kafka do fine-grained intra-topic permissioning?

If not, what is the canonical solution to this?

Comment: AFAIK, no server-side security feature of Kafka allows you filter messages your consumers receive based on message content. If you control the client, you can do your filtering at the Consumer level.

Comment: @AlexandreJuma okay. But do we have permissioning granularity at least at the topic level? IE consumer 1 can see topics A, B C, but not topics D and E, and consumer 2 can see topics C, D and E but not A and B? If this is the case, then I can probably get around the problem using topics, since I've just read that one can have a lot more topics than I  initially thought possible.

Comment: if you encrypt the messages with different keys you can control who gets the keys. if you create a delay server then you can often distribute the exchange data more freely. if you create an entitlements server then you can control who can connect to the entitlements server and which message types get filtered (for example implemented as a KSQL query or a KSQL UDF)

Comment: @HansJespersen is KSQL part of open source Kafka, or is it Confluent only? I'm not a huge fan of the crypto solution because it's quite a lot of work client-side. Entitlements server: can you recommend a blog post or paper where I can read more about this? Alternatively, put in a full answer? I I know I could just create new KSQL or Kafka streams-based topics for each separate user but this seems inefficient. 
Would the entitlements server be any different?

Comment: KSQL is Confluent community licensed so free, and the source is available. Let’s you do content based filtering of messages and either output to another topic, or stream directly to a client via HTTP(S) so not via kafka client at all.  I have no blog to point to on Entitlements servers but this is a very common thing is all Market Data Distribution Systems (MDDS) including non-Kafka based systems. Thompson Reuters and Bloomberg and others all write their own on top of messaging as part of their MDDS.

Comment: Xignite (https://xignite.com) as an example has built an entire MDDS on top of Kafka with all the Exchange feeds from around the world and make available as a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Out of the box Apache Kafka cannot do “fine-grained intra topic permissioning”.

You will have to write a custom Kafka Serializer/Deserializer (SerDes) library or implement your own Entitlements Server in the middle to provide Role Based Access Control (RBAC) and content based filtering.

If you break the data into different topics then yes, basic Kafka ACL can control access to the topic but that was not the original question and you aren’t going to make 6 million topics in kafka.

The original question was about having one topic that mixes different types of data. For that you need to have a client-side deserializer that reads all the data and then filters out certain messages based on what the entitlement server says they are allowed to see.

If you are concerned that client side should never receive data that it is not allowed to receive, even deep in the client-side stack, then you can encrypt the messages with different keys and you can control who gets the keys.

Comment: How will this work technically? I assume different "grains" of permissioning require their own topics? For example if consumer A is permissioned for the "CME_data" topic but not for the "Reuters_data" topic, can Kafka ensure that consumer A only receives messages carried on the CME_data topic? Because I can see how you would get different permissions from an entitlements server, but I don't know how technically it would then "switch on" certain feeds for you on Kafka.

Comment: If the data is in separate topics then normal Kafka ACLs will work but if you have one topic with mixed data then you need client side code that will read all the data and then filter the messages that the user is not entitled to see out of the stream. If you change the entitlement rules in the entitlement server then then next time the deserializer checks for new entitlement rules it will start applying the new filtering and allow or deny certain messages

Comment: I have taken the liberty of condensing all your comments into one (excellent - thank you) answer. Please feel free to undo if you like.